# Selecting 5 pairs of men and 5 women from 10 women and 12 men

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

### Question

> A dance class consists of $22$ students, of which $10$
> are women and $12$ are men. If $5$ men and $5$ women
> are to be chosen and then paired off, how many
> results are possible?

### Approach

According to me, the number of results possible is:

$$\binom{10}{5}*\binom{12}{5}*5!*2^{5}$$

Answer given :

$$\binom{10}{5}*\binom{12}{5}*5!$$

### My conclusion

Shouldn't be there $2$ options in each pair i.e ordering between men and women for $5$ such group, making it $5!$? Why is the answer not leaving $5!$? Are they not considering order? And if the order is important, is my answer correct in this case?

Comment: Why would the be two options in each pair . A pair is of combination of a man    and a woman . Even if you select fist a man then a woman to pair him or select first a woman and then a man to pair her both are same

Comment: if order is important, ur answer is right i believe

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct if ["Fred and Ginger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Astaire_and_Ginger_Rogers) is counted as a distinct pairing from "Ginger and Fred".

Answer (score 2):

First select five men and women. Then select one man $M_1$ at random, and pair him off with one of the 5 different women. Next select another man $M_2$, and assign him to one of the 4 remaining women. Continuing this, there are $5!$ ways to pair off the 5 selected men and women. As such, the total number of pairs equals:

$${10 \choose 5}{12 \choose 5}5!$$

The order in which the pairs are chosen does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{10}{5}*\binom{12}{5}*5!*2^{5}$$ is the right answer if the order in which you pick the pair is important. For example, if(x,y) and (y,x) are different.